# What is going on with the Environment Hub Pilot?

Tags: summer-13

The highly needed feature to manage multi org environments from inside Salesforce.com (no external, insecure Password Manager tools) called Environment Hub was announced one year ago as a Pilot and this pilot was postponed until Summer '13.

I immediatelly opened a case to ask to take part and this is what came back:

> "Please be informed that the Environment Hub pilot program is no
>   longer being offered. Our R&D team have decided to decommission this
>   program and they are looking to replace it with another program in the
>   future. Please stay tuned for any new features in future releases."

Is this really true?! As in the documentation it is still referenced. Any idea why Salesforce.com discontinues this great feature?

Comment: I did the same thing as you, opened a case and was most upset about this feature being decommissioned. So I pushed for more info and my case rep has just informed me that the Product Manager is going to respond to this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is going GA in Winter 14...
[Winter '14 release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_winter14_release_notes.pdf)

Comment: This now live, and whilst a bit complicated to get up and running, works great!

Answer (score 7):

I am the Product Manager of this feature. The plan is to do a limited pilot in Summer'13 with a planned GA (Generally Available) in Winter'14 (Safe Harbor - GA date is subject to change). I am in the process of setting up the pilot and when I do so, I will post on this thread. The Pilot feature set is limited in functionality and may not be useful / applicable for everyone.

Comment: I am **very** keen to get on this pilot. My case number was #09406875

Comment: We at Up2Go are also very keen to get on this pilot. We opened the Case #09424239.

Comment: We just were asked to submit a request for this pilot. Seems to be open again.